# In JavaScript how to get second of current day?

Tags: javascript, time, seconds

So the question is described in title. I need to get current second of the day using JavaScript.

Comment: Do you mean the seconds part of the current time, e.g., if it's 5:38:26 pm you want 26? Or do you mean the number of seconds since midnight? Or...?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You add up the bits:

```
var dt = new Date();
var secs = dt.getSeconds() + (60 * dt.getMinutes()) + (60 * 60 * dt.getHours());
```

or if you prefer

```
var dt = new Date();
var secs = dt.getSeconds() + (60 * (dt.getMinutes() + (60 * dt.getHours())));
```

Comment: If you plan to store it somewhere consider using `getUTCHours` and `getUTCMinutes`

Answer (score 2):

For example ([in action](http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/zsmBc/)):

```
​var today = new Date(), today_abs = new Date(), today_secs = 0;
today_abs.setHours(0);
today_abs.setMinutes(0);
today_abs.setSeconds(0);
today_secs = (today.getTime() - today_abs.getTime()) / 1000;​
```

Comment: Is this method faster than the multiplication?